# Kotlin: Method not able to be used with generics

Tags: generics, kotlin

As the flip side of this:

```
interface PacketDecoder<out T : Packet> : PacketTranscoder {

    fun decode(client: Client, buf: ByteBuf): T

}
```

I am trying to use this:

```
interface PacketEncoder<in T : Packet> : PacketTranscoder {

    fun encode(packet: T, buf: ByteBuf)

}
```

While `PacketDecoder` seems to work fine, I cannot refer to the `encode(T, ByteBuf)` method. IntelliJ IDEA auto-complete doesn't even show it as an option and manually writing it results in an unresolved reference error.

To get around it I am currently using this hack but I don't believe this is the proper way to do this.

```
fun <P : T> encode(packet: P, buf: ByteBuf)
```

Comment: I've tries to implement it in Idea and it works great without errors.
https://gist.github.com/alien11689/67ac3edbe562555acc7f

Comment: Works here: http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/hrcd2j34aellk5fdg7gv7sfeei/u9ue9h9dr1tkv98gdpthh3dea1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn't work is because I was referring from a value `HashMap<KClass<*>, PacketEncoder<*>>()` thus Kotlin couldn't generate the signature of the `encode` method as `*` isn't a valid generic signature (could somebody confirm?).

This is my resulting code, I had to use an unchecked cast to `PacketEncoder<T>`:

```
fun <T : Packet> encode(packet: T, buf: ByteBuf) {
    val encoder = (encoders[packet.javaClass.kotlin] ?: return) as PacketEncoder<T>
    buf.writeByte(encoder.id)
    encoder.encode(packet, buf)
}
```